# what is the concentration of EDTA after titration with Zinc Metal?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, titration

I take $\pu{1g}$ of zinc metal and after dissolving, diluting it to $\pu{500 ml}$ and adjust the $\mathrm{pH}$ of $\pu{50 ml}$ of it to make titration with an unknown concentration of EDTA.

I found $\pu{1g}$ of zinc took $\pu{25 ml}$ of EDTA that means $\pu{0.004 g}$ of zinc equivalent to $\pu{1ml}$ of unknown concentration of EDTA.

my question is how can I calculate the concentration of EDTA from the above information?

Comment: From the mass of zinc, you can calculate the quantity of titrated material (using its molar mass).
You write the relation between the quantities of matter at equivalence (according to the equation of the dosage reaction): the only unknown is the concentration of EDTA

Comment: please more clarify what do you mean?

Comment: 1) what is the equation of the dosage équation ?
2) you know the mass of zinc $m_{zinc}$ —> what is the relation beetween $m_{zinc}$ and the quantity of matter $n_{zinc}$ ?

Comment: Zn2+ (aq) + EDTA4- (aq) ---- Zn(EDTA)2- (aq)

Comment: With this equation, what is the relation beetween the quantities of matter ?

Comment: (mass of zinc / molar mass of zinc )X (1000)= ( molarity of EDTA x Volume Of EDTA )

Comment: it's correct using the right units (be careful with the factor 1000)

Comment: what is the mass that should be compensated in equation 1g or 0.004?... 2)(be careful with the factor 1000) ....what do you mean?

Comment: « that means 0.004 g of zinc equivalent to 1ml of unknown concentration of EDTA. » : you have the response 

Comment: you mean the concentration of EDTA become 0.004 mol?! ....really I'm very confused

Comment: No, you say that 0,004g of zinc is équivalent to 1mL from the unknown EDTA : use the equation beetween the quantities of matter

Comment: (0.004/65.38)X1000=(molarity of EDTA x 1) ...am i right ?

Comment: Yes that’s correct

Comment: Also, OP's statement of "$\pu{0.004 g}$ of zinc equivalent to $\pu{1ml}$ of unknown concentration of EDTA" is incorrect as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since OP has productive conversation with Nicolas, I think the information extracted from chain of comments is good enough to convince OP has made fair enough effort to solve this homework. The following steps might be helpful as well:

OP didn't indicate what $\ce{Zn/EDTA}$ molar ratio would this reaction take. As rule of thumb, it is generally $1:1$. Thus, $\pu{1 g}$ of $\ce{Zn}$ took $\pu{25 ml}$ of $\ce{EDTA}$ solution at the end point, that means the amount of $\ce{EDTA}$ in $\pu{25 ml}$ of the solution is $\frac{\pu{1 g}}{\pu{65.38 g mol-1}} = \pu{0.015 mol}$ (where $\pu{65.38 g mol-1}$ is the atomic mass of $\ce{Zn}$). Therefore, molarity of $\ce{EDTA}$ solution is $\frac{\pu{0.015 mol}}{\pu{0.025 L}} = \pu{0.6 mol L-1}$.

**Note:** According to the given data, the answer should be in one significant figure.

Comment: the very helpful answer, thanks a lot